# Creating symbolic links resulting in 500 error

Tags: centos, cpanel, symlink, whm

Currently running a WHM / Cpanel server running Centos. Server seems to be running fine no issues there. However I'm using a deployment process to put files outside of the document root. e.g.

> ~/deployment

instead of:

> ~/public_html

Obviously I need to point public_html to this folder so my site will run. So, I'm removing the **public_html** and creating a symlink and pointing it to the new **deployment** folder. This results in a 500 error.

So looking at the logs I've discovered that it produces the following error:

> Directory "/home/xyz/deployment" is writeable by group

Checking the file permissions looks as though the symlink is **777** where i need it to be **755** for the server to allow viewing.

Is there a setting in WHM ? Is there a setting in Centos? I have another box running that doesn't have this issue so I'm assuming that this is related to the current setup of this machine.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

when you create a hard link from a file or folder, This file/folder inherits the accesses and permissions of the original file/folder, and in soft link it will be 777 permission, so i think you can use rsync options for both purpose :

1- have a folder with all files in source

2- have your own permissions in folder